# dynamically created buttons to call by a selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

guys i have a ajax that creates a dynamic buttons, each button has a counter on their id. im trying to select each button and add a class to them.

```
   var html;
                $.ajax({
                          type:'POST',
                          url:'add_subject.php',
                     dataType:'json',
                         data:{'func_numbr':'6'},
                      success:function (data){
                           var counter_sub = 0 ;
                         $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                          if(data[i].subjct_statu == "0"){
                            $('#inactivate['+counter_sub+']').addClass("inactiveButton");
                           }
                          html = "<tr>";

                          html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject["+counter_sub+"]' rel='"+data[i].subj_id+"' value='"+data[i].subj_name+"'></td>";
                          html += "<td><input type='button' id='activate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button active  ' value='Apply'  > ";
                          html += "<input type='button' id='inactivate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button inactive' value='Remove from list'></td>";
                          html += "</tr>";
                 $('#curr-4thhigh-tble').append(html);

                 counter_sub = counter_sub +1;
                });
                      }     
               });
```

but wat im doing is not working i guess something is wrong. plss help tnx in advanced

Comment: It seems to me like your giving classes to elements that you create on the next line, i.e. they don't exist yet?

Comment: yes because they will dynamically created when ajax calls

Comment: You can't add a class to something that does'nt exist with `addClass`, it does'nt work that way. The selector `$('#inactivate['+counter_sub+']')` will return absolutely nothing as the element does'nt exist.

Comment: is there any way to do that? but when I remove my counter in the id and add a class to it it works: 

$('#inactivate').addClass(".inactiveButton");


html += "<input type='button' id='inactivate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button inactive ' value='Remove from list'></td>";

Comment: Yes, add the class when you create the element, like in the answer below. There are some typos in your code aswell, there is no "lable" element etc. and if you're not using this with some sort of serverside framework drop the brackets in the ID's and use underscores instead.

Comment: what this will print: $('#inactivate['+counter_sub+']') = like inactivate0 or inactivate[0].

Comment: inactivate[0] supposedly but is guess it wont work

Comment: You really need to keep better track of your HTML, and I'd suggestion another approach completely -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbwYx/) -- as that would at least ensure the elements are created with the proper attributes and closings (you're not closing the last TD in your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, it should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add_subject.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'func_numbr': '6'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var counter_sub = 0,
            classToAdd = "";
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            classToAdd = "";
            if (data[i].subjct_statu == "0") {
                classToAdd = "inactiveButton";
                //$('#inactivate[' + counter_sub + ']').addClass("inactiveButton");
            }
            html = "<tr>";

            html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject[" + counter_sub + "]' rel='" + data[i].subj_id + "' value='" + data[i].subj_name + "'></td>";
            html += "<td><input type='button' id='activate[" + counter_sub + "]' name='active' class='button active  ' value='Apply'  > ";
            html += "<input type='button' id='inactivate[" + counter_sub + "]' name='active' class='button inactive " + classToAdd + "' value='Remove from list'></td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            $('#curr-4thhigh-tble').append(html);
            counter_sub = counter_sub + 1;
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend adding the class to them as they are created like other comments/answer suggest .  But.. to answer your question this is how you select all elements that have an id containing "myID"

```
       $("[id*='+myID+']")
```

or in a loop

```
        $("[id*='+myID" + counter_sub + "']")
```